# Why double brackets when selecting multiple rows from a data frame using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a data frame `df` and want to select multiple rows.

Using `.iloc` I can do `df.iloc[1:8]`, but doing the same using `.loc` requires either doing

```
df.loc[1:8]
```

or

```
df.loc[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,]]
```

I am curious to know about the reasoning behind the double brackets for the. loc

Comment: posible duplicated of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417991/pandas-why-are-double-brackets-needed-to-select-column-after-boolean-indexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Why are double brackets needed to select column after boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417991/pandas-why-are-double-brackets-needed-to-select-column-after-boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.loc[]` method is a label based method that means it takes names or labels of the index when taking the slices, whereas `.iloc[]` method is based on the index's position.

To answer your question: the arguments of `.loc` are

- row label
- list of row labels : (double brackets) means that you can pass the list of rows when you need to work with specific set of rows.
  example. you will have row indices when you use cross validation techniques.